# ReactJS, redirect after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router, higher-order-functions

Is there a way or how can I redirect after some `return` on `render`?

What I want is to do something like this:

```
render() {
  return(<div>You have no access</div>)
  // then redirect to "/"
```

I was thinking on create a component that only has a redirect in `componentDidMount` after 3 seconds, for example called `<Redirect>` then use it like this:

```
render() {
  return(<Redirect time=3> <div>You have no access</div> </Redirect>
  // then redirect to "/"
```

Redirect.js

```
componentDidMount() {
  // code for redirect using with this.props.time
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that kind of redirect.

Since you can pass data during routing, it's possible to pass the prev URL to this component, in order to replace the `/`, achieving `return to prev page`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const intervalId = setInterval(this.timer, 1500);
  this.setState({ intervalId: intervalId });
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
}
timer = () => {
  this.props.history.push("/");
};
```

The only thing left is to make it a common component, or a HOC for `auth` check, based on the code demand.

---

[image]

Try it online:

[image: Edit cranky-chatelet-quoy7]

Comment: Why interval, though? You meant timeout?

Comment: @yuriy636 Yes since the post said we need a timeout.